# Installing aircrack in ubuntu 14.04.03. When running make install I receive the following message:

Tags: 14.04

When running make install I receive the following message:

[*]Run 'airodump-ng-oui-update' as root (or with sudo) to install or update Airodump-ng OUI file (Internet Connection requied).

I have completed this action but the error still persists when trying to run make install.

All suggestions welcome.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: just to check, you do run make install itself using sudo?

Comment: Sorry for being late - work comes first I'm afraid..yes I run make install using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, you have successfully installed Aircrack. With

```
sudo airodump-ng-oui-update
```

you downloads and parses IEEE OUI list.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I've successfully updated using your advice.